# Best practice starting a project on Vue-Cli

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, vue-cli

community.

I have noticed that when I start a new Vue-Cli project using an existing file with a `src` content I should create the development environment installing `npm` an so on, resulting on the development server to be run by entering `npm run dev` differently from the cases when I create a new project from scratch in Webstorm, resulting therefore in entering `npm run serve` on the terminal once I run the development server. What is the difference in these two cases, side-effects and best practices?

And specially, why is there this difference after all?

Comment: Do you mind explaining more in detail how is the npm way, which steps do you take?

Comment: `npm run dev` is not documented in the vue-cli documentation. So, just use `npm run serve` to develop.

Comment: You probably have outdated Vue-CLI. The newest creates script in package.json `serve` not `dev`.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Orlov's comment about using old vue-cli is absolutely correct. You're probably using old vue cli in your terminal. Webstorm is possibly generating the project from the latest version.

In addition to that, `npm run dev` and `npm run serve` are just npm scripts defined in `package.json`. You can change the command to any name you like. The best practice generally is to NOT alter the name set by cli tools and just use them directly.

Comment: Yes...I agree that it's correct. But I finally understand that my case is more specific. I am using an up to date Vue-Cli. What is going on is that I am actually retrieving old files form an Udemy course and then building my development environment on top of these files. I will build projects from scratch instead then replace just the given "start code" src files upon the creation of the fresh new project in WebStorm. What do you think regarding this approach? Would there be another best practice in my specific case, considering my statement in this comment?

Comment: In that case, the Webstorm project will simply take care of everything. You just need to arrange your code in the `src` folder according to your needs